# What is DialogResult function visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am working a simple form, I spend more than a day to find out something

What I want is to click a button in form1 and then pop up a form2. I have the following code

```
private: System::Void MyAdd_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         Form2^ myForm2 = gcnew Form2();

     }
};
```

However, the form2 could not pop up. I really don't understand, so I copy more code from an example. Even though I don't think it will be useful, just try. However it works.

```
private: System::Void MyAdd_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         Form2^ myForm2 = gcnew Form2();
         if (myForm2->ShowDialog()==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {}
     }
};
```

My question is that I have already created the form in both case, why the IF statement makes difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it makes no difference since nothing extra is done. However, a common usage is [like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx#Y693):

```
void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2^ testDialog = gcnew Form2;

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if ( testDialog->ShowDialog( this ) == ::DialogResult::OK )
   {

      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this->txtResult->Text = testDialog->TextBox1->Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this->txtResult->Text = "Cancelled";
   }

   delete testDialog;
}
```

Checking the [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) allows you to see how the dialog closed.

If you are asking why you need to call `ShowDialog`, it is because even though you have created your form, you have not told the system to show it yet. Note that `ShowDialog` blocks/does not return until the dialog box is closed.